# Distributing Xamarin iOS app from AppCenter/HockeyApp

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I can build and debug the Xamarin iOS app on the iPad without issues. The problem is when installing from the AppCenter or HockeyApp.

I am using a distribution identity and a distribution provisioning profile for both debugging directly on the iPad and when uploading to the AppCenter and HockeyApp.

[image]

The only difference really is the Debug mode for local debugging and Ad-Hoc mode when uploading to the AppCenter/HockeyApp.

When downloading and installing from the AppCenter/HockeyApp the icon shows up and the following status is seeing:
Loading, Installing and then nothing the icon is just there, greyed out, clicking on it does nothing... I rebooted the iPad and now the icon shows as "Waiting..." when I click on it the popup shows up saying that something went wrong with the installation.

[image]

[image]

App just sits there, greyed out. clicking on it does nothing.
[image]

"Waiting..." Only shows up after rebooting...

[image]

Clicking on it displays the pop-up. (Only after rebooting..)
[image]

Any ideas on how to get the app to install properly via AppCenter or HockeyApp?

Here are the logs when installing from the web...
The only thing I see is `Application is invalid` but why!?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To narrow the issue, I always try to install the release of the ipa through XCode.

1. Connect your iPhone with Mac.
2. Open Xcode
3. Select Windows --> Device and Simulators
4. Select your device from the "Connected" list
5. Drag your ipa into the "Installed Apps" list.

[image]

You can quickly determine if the issue occurs inside the ipa.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like your UDID isn't added to your Ad-Hoc provisioning profile. When creating/editing the profile, you need to make sure that the device you want to install it onto is selected in the list of devices. It is the 3rd screen (app id, certificate, devices).
2. You could be trying to install an app that is already installed with a different profile. If you install the debug app with the development profile and then try to install it with an ad-hoc, it won't let you. The console log will complain about some kind of mismatch with the bundle. Try deleting the app before installing it.

If that doesn't fix it for you, you should look through the console logs when trying to install the app and see if it gives the error.

Comment: It's not the UDID. One,  just doubled checked , two, I can deploy directly to my iPad with that provisioning. Direct deploy would not work if the device wasn't included. The app is not installed when I try installing from AppCenter or HockeyApp.  How can I see logs when installing something from the web?

Comment: @FabioS. You can check the device's console logs as described here: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/known-issues-with-ios#inspect-console-log
Note though that HockeyApp does not alter the actual binary, so whatever issue you're running into has to be with the app itself.